# Sharepoint site keeps refreshing endlessly

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, alternate-access-mapping

When I entered the public ip address of my sharepoint site in chrome, it keeps refreshing non-stop.

I entered my username & password, but it keeps refreshing and prompting for my credentials again and again. Could this be a mapping problem or server issue? Has anyone faced such an issue before?

I'm using sharepoint 2013 foundation by the way.

AAM configuration:

- Default: public ip (http://external/)
- Intranet: http://sales/
- Internet: https://sales/

Comment: Could you try to disable **loop Back Check** as mentioned at [Configure AAM in SP 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/02/26/configure-alternate-access-mapping-in-sharepoint-server-2013/)

Comment: You're welcome, please share the setting of AAM but try to hide the IP and other private info!

Comment: @MohamedEl-QassasMVP I've put in the AAM config. Let me know if you need anymore information thanks. By the way, that issue only happens with other browsers on phones & IE especially, but with chrome on Desktop it seems to work fine (after trying out)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71808/discussion-on-question-by-denise-sharepoint-site-keeps-refreshing-endlessly).

Answer (score 0):

Check if "Request Management" service has enabled on all servers (APPs and WFEs) . if yes , please disable RM service on all servers.